# How to subscribe to Multiple Eth addresses on USDT token transfer events

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have a list of Eth user deposit addresses. They can make External USDT transfers to these addresses. How do I subscribe to the USDT contract and filter for all the User Addresses I have for deposits. My user numbers would keep growing.

I understand I can filter Transfer events on 1 to address. But how do I filter on a addresses in the order of thousands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the web3 event handler `options` object ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events)) to subscribe to transfers to only specified recipients.

Example:

```
usdtContract.events.Transfer({
    filter: {
        // `to` is the name of the indexed Solidity event topic, as in
        // `event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value)`
        to: ["0x123", "0x456", "0x789"]
    }
}, (err, data) => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Can I keep updating this list dynamically as more and more users join?

Comment: @Manjush08 To update the list, you'll need to reinitialize the handler with the new list. Currently you can do that only by destructing the `usdtContract` object and invoking the handler again... Or you can use the generic web3 `subscribe` handler and its method `unsubscribe()` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html?highlight=unsubscribe#subscribe)) that allows you to unsubscribe and resubscribe again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. One more doubt, do you think the listener would be able to handle say a million of user addresses in the list (in memory?). I wanted to know if this is in fact the correct way of monitoring deposits to user deposit addresses.

Comment: @Manjush08 I've never tried this in practice but I'm guessing it would **not** work with that large array. Not because of memory issues in the JS app, but these filter params are actually sent to a node that your app is connected to. So I'm guessing most nodes have an arbitrary limit of how many values they can filter against and it's probably lower than a million. Maybe few hundreds or a thousand at most? ... For this large amount of addresses, I'd recommend scaling your app to multiple instances (each for a subset of addresses) and connect to multiple nodes (one node per each app instance).